# What Is This Part Of A Linq Query Called?

Tags: linq

In the LINQ query below, what do you call the "a"?

```
var result = 
from a in db.table
where a.id == 12
select new {A = a};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a *range variable*. See my Edulinq post on ["how query expressions work"](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Hey, you're cheating! You've got all the answers precomputed, so you can get away with simple sentence and a link to a great blog post!

Comment: Thanks, I will be adding that to my personal programming vocabulary.